# ERROR: GEOSIntersects - Calculating intersection of tracks and buffered tracks

Tags: postgis, intersection

I am using the following code to calculate intersections between tracks and buffered tracks:

```
tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    st_setsrid(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created),4326) AS track from 
    subset_cr  
    GROUP BY imei
),


bufferedtracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created),4326)::geography,5)::geometry geom from 
    subset_cr  
    GROUP BY imei
) 
 
,
 
intersections_cte as(
select imei, intimei, st_length(st_union(intgeom)::geography) intlength, st_union(intgeom) as intersecting_track 
from
(
select a.imei, b.imei intimei, 
    (st_dump(st_intersection(a.geom,b.track))).geom intgeom 
  from
  bufferedtracks a,
  tracks b
  where a.imei != b.imei and st_intersects(a.geom,b.track)
) allints
group by imei, intimei

)
```

The total intersection of the tracks is then given by:

```
select sum (intlength) from intersections_cte
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
ERROR: GEOSIntersects: TopologyException: side location conflict at
```

Comment: That error can happen if one of the argument geometries to `ST_Intersects` is invalid. You can check validity with `ST_IsValid`, and repair it with `ST_MakeValid`.

Comment: st_intersects(ST_MakeValid(a.geom) , ST_MakeValid(b.track)) should solve it?

Comment: Maybe.  Although linear geometries are usually always valid, so that might not be necessary.  It would be best to isolate the geometries causing the issue (and when found report them here).